# Why does the path to a file in another dir start sometimes with "./" and sometimes with "../"

Tags: python

I have a file structure that looks like this:

```
-Project
    -trainingData
        - Folder1
        - Folder2
    -python
        - get_files.py
    -train_model.py
```

If I want to iterate over each folder in my folder trainingData I use the following function:

```
data = os.listdir(path_data)
for folder in data:
    # Do sth
```

path_data is ***"../training_data"*** in this case. Which makes sense because I need to go one level up and then into the trainingData folder. In cmd I would also type *"cd .."* and then *"cd trainingData"*

But why is the path ***"./training_data"*** when I call the function in *get_files.py* from *train_model.py*. This does not make sense to me. Isn't the relativ path still the same if I would call the function in *get_files.py* from the file itself?

Comment: "Isn't the relativ path still the same if I would call the function in get_files.py from the file itself?" No, the path starts at the "current workng dir", which is dir from which the ""main"" script was executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative path is from the __main__ script, in this case train_model.py. If this wasn't the case then every library or script you imported could all have different relative paths and things would get screwy quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Because the path is relative to the python file being executed. in this case. `train_model.py`

Answer (score 1):

> why is the path "./training_data" when I call the function in get_files.py from train_model.py

Because you are calling the file from `train_model.py` hence the *relative path* is changed (relative to the current running file).

In order to check the *Absolute Path* you can use [os.path.abspath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) or [os.path.realpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=realpath#os.path.realpath).

---

Also the newest [Path.resolve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve):

> Make the path absolute, resolving any symlinks. A new path object is returned: